# why if we pad any signal with enough zeros we can get the same result

Tags: fft

if we pad any signal with enough zeros we can get the same result as linear 
convolution whilst using the fft function we compute circular convolution. 
Why?

Comment: It's usually thought of as the other way around.  The windowing you choose impacts a trade-off between frequency and time resolution regarding non-stationary data.  You may have to prioritize.

Comment: can you explain more plz?

Comment: Just curious, in practical implementations, is there a relationship between the time resolution and frequency resolution? @hotpaw?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  try computing the linear convolution of $~[1\quad 1\quad  1]~$ and 
$~[0\quad 1 \quad 1]~$ by hand and the circular convolution of the zero-padded
versions
$~[1\quad 1\quad  1 \quad 0\quad 0\quad 0]~$ and $~[0\quad 1 \quad 1\quad 0\quad 0\quad 0]~$ also by hand (or via FFTs if you are desperate enough).

Comment: I know how to do linear convolution but what is circular convolution or how can i compute circular convolution using fft